How much electromagnetic force is keeping a chair together?
I’m not a physicist, so excuse my poor wording.
In an average chair, roughly how much attractive force from the electromagnetic field is keeping it together?
If you want to go further, how much force from the strong and weak forces are keeping it together as well, with their essential roles for the nucleus?
How do you calculate such things for an area of interacting particles?

Your question is necessarily non-well-posed because forces are not well-defined in quantum physics, and without considering directions, you can choose any arbitrarily large value and say that that is the forces. Forces are not conserved and so you can just make stuff up as large as you want.

Attractive force between what and what? Neighboring molecules?

I would answer this by looking at the minimum force required to make the chair not a chair. Depending on the construction of the chair and the application of the force, that could be a few hundreds to thousands of newtons. Such forces are entirely electromagnetic. It is not necessary to break strong or weak nuclear bonds in order to break a chair
